# Mongoose - get single field from array of subdocuments

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a document, `Model` like this:

```
{
    name: String,
    user: String,
    components: [{
      alias: String,
      name: String,
      ...etc...
    }]

}
```

I'd like to formulate a reponse that just returns an array of `component.alias` for a given document.
E.g, if I have:

```
{
  name: "doc1",
  components: [{alias: "alias1", ...}, {alias: "alias2", ...}]
}
```

I'd like to just end up with `["alias1", "alias2"]`

So far I have:

```
    Model.findById(
         modelId,
         { "components.alias": 1, _id: 0 },
         (err, docs) => {
            console.log(docs)
         }
      );
```

But this gives me:

```
{
    "components": [
        {
            "alias": "alias1"
        }
    ]
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: As suggested in the marked dupe, the solution is `Model.distinct("components.alias", {_id: modelId }, (err, docs) => { console.log(docs) });`

Answer (score 2):

Use aggregate for that, MongoDB query for that.

```
db.getCollection('Model').aggregate([
    { "$unwind": "$components" },
     { "$group": { "_id": "$components.alias" }}
]).map(function(el) { return el._id })
```

Node.js code

```
Model.aggregate([
            { "$match": { "name": "doc1" } }, // any condition
            { "$unwind": "$components" },
            { "$group": { "_id": "$name", components: { $push: "$components.alias" } } }
        ]).then((data)=>console.log(data))
```

Output:

```
{
    "_id": "doc1",
    "emails": [
        "alias1",
        "alias2"
    ]
}
```